# Is it bad to comment an old question?

Tags: discussion, comments, old-questions

Recently by going through questions I reach this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50492547/how-do-you-reference-this-in-java-by-using-a-variable) which leads me to this [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445185/assign-this-to-a-variable).

The question is badly asked as it does not show any research effort. And I supposed that's why it is downvoted. And as it's said when you downvote "please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved". obviously the downvoters did not respect the advice as they did not leave a comment. So I think I could leave a comment to explain the OP why some users downvoted, and so suggest improvements.

**edit:** the comments has been removed, so it was probably wrong... It was something like "Question has been downvoted cause it shows neither research effort nor attempt"

A user point out that my comment seems useless, by asking me "what is the point of this comment since the question is really old". And he's not wrong. since the question is really old, there's a few chances that my comment is useful. And even less chances that the OP improve his question.

But also I've just followed the advice given when you mouse over the "add comment" button : "use comment to suggest improvements". And my comment, if it's not seen and use by OP, will be useful to next user since it explain why this is a badly asked question. Moreover, I think it's not because a question is old that it does not need to be improved, commented, edited, answered, etc.

So I just want some other opinion about this kind of comment. (Not about this specific case, but generic opinion). TLDR : Is it bad to comment an old question ?

Comment: It is generally not a fantastic idea to remind a user with thousands of rep and hundreds of posts in the [java] tag about an obvious java detail.  He already knows.  Just don't use the @ in the comment if you want to ensure that the questioner knows.

Comment: "Question has been downvoted cause it shows neither research effort nor attempt" is not a improvement suggestion. It is just a statement why you downvoted, not some advice how the question can be improved.

Answer (score 4):

The user hasn't even been on the site in the past 5 years.

There's no point in trying to get them to improve the question.  It's a lost cause.  Just downvote and move on.  Save your time trying to help authors improve for questions that actually have a realistic shot of being improved (where the user is active, the question is salvageable, and the author appears interested in actually fixing it).

Comment: I think a comment pointing out how the question could have been improved is still helpful. Even if OP doesn't come back others who stumble across this question will get an idea of how to ask better questions. The question has been viewed almost 800 times. At least some of them were likely people new to Stack Overflow and may have been tempted to ask a similar question themselves.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic The type of user who would actually care to read comments like that, remember them, and follow them (at which point we're talking about fraction of a percent of the user base here) is the type of user that would be reading the help center and advice shown when asking a question, and so doesn't need to see such a comment.

Comment: Unless the downvote reason is non-obvious...

Comment: @user202729 So what do you think are the odds that someone is going to read a question where that question has uncommon problems not addressed by the help center, read those comments, understand it, then ask a new question, have the *same* problem, remember the comment that they read earlier (most likely quite a long time earlier) and then fix the question as a result?  I'd be surprised if one in a thousand comments you end up posting to such a question would actually have a shot at doing all of those things.  And all to save someone the effort of posting the same comment on the new question.

Comment: No, it's just not a useful way to spend your time.  Spend your time helping to improve questions that actually have a shot at being improved.  They're easy enough to find.